# Replace list bullet by custom symbol (right aligned)

Tags: html, css

I need to build a menu that (on hover) will "popup" a sub-menu, having a description and a list of sub-menu of level 2. Actually for test purpose I don't hide the sub-menus.

My test code:

```css
.menu-l1>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.details {
    position: absolute;
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 1em;    
    ul {
        direction: rtl;
        margin-left: 0;
        li {
            text-align: center;
            &:nth-child(odd) {
                background: lightblue;
            }
            &:nth-child(even) {
                background: lightgreen;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-l1">
    <li><a href="#">first menu</a>
        <div class="details">
            <div>header</div>
            <ul class="menu-l2">
                <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub long</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">second menu</a>
        <div class="details">
            <div>2 header</div>
            <ul class="menu-l2">
                <li><a href="#">1 sub-menu long</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 sub-menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This gives (when SCSS activated) something like this ([JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JDERf/597/))

[image]

This is OK, because I need that bullet of the list be right aligned, the text center aligned.

1. I need to replace the bullet with custom symbol ">";

   1.* Ideally the ">" symbol should be "linked" with the main link
2. I need fo fix the "bug" of the second sub-menu when displaying *numbers* at right (?) (should be "2 sub-menu" instead of "sub-menu 2")...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JDERf/598/

Here only changes:

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    li {
        a {
            display: block;
            padding:0 1em 0 0;
            position: relative;
            &:after {
                content:">";
                position: absolute;
                right:0;
            }
        }
    }
```

You don't need rtl for this. You can use :before or :after pseudo-element and set any character or background image for it. It is better to make link bigger with `display:block` and position our pseudo-element relative to it.

Comment: It was exactly I was looked for. Thanks a lot!